# WhatsApp Google Drive restore fails

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I migrated to a new phone yesterday (Nexus 5 -> Pixel 2) and wanted to restore my WhatsApp chat history on the new device. I've always used the Google Drive backup feature, so I thought this should have been relatively easy. However, during the restoring process, the progress bar gets stuck at 31%. Some minutes later, the app informs me that restoring the messages failed.

What can I do? The Google Drive backup file seems to be corrupted, so I also made a manual copy of the msgstore.db.crypt12 file, so that I could maybe use that in order to restore my history. However, the steps listed on the Whatsapp website (https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/20887921/) do not work for me, since it always tries to restore the backup found on Google Drive.

Comment: I actually did this. Same problem. It just gets stuck at 31% and then tells me it failed. Whatsapp support itself is useless - they don't even really read the question.

Answer (score 2):

**If your old device is with you**

- Delete WhatsApp backup from Google Drive. [See steps from WhatsApp FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000019/?category=5245251#delete)
- Redo Google drive backup manually (Settings → chats → chat backup → Google drive) and restore

That will create a *fresh* backup  so corruption is ruled out, though would take longer

**Old device not with you but you have copy of database file**

- Uninstall WhatsApp
- Install Whatsapp and  on successfully activating it, immediately disconnect from Internet
- Copy the database file into the same folder location from which you copied and restore

Comment: If you choose second method, on successful restore it still makes sense to repeat first step (except restore) to ensure you have a uncorrupted backup

Comment: I will try your first idea after the weekend (I'll be travelling). Thank you! Have you actually tried out that approach before?

Comment: Not personally but from a friend who did this successfully with a similar problem of aborted restore

Comment: Still no luck... it keeps crashing at 31%, even when I use a newly made backup :(

Comment: That's really strange and can't figure out

Comment: Not your problem :) it's WhatsApp that just does a terrible job of fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had something like that too, then I tried on another phone and it worked on it. Then I backed up again and it then worked on the first phone that it didn't work in the first place. So try using another phone, maybe it helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and actually fixed it, it's a bug that reverses the resorted backup again for some reason.. so all you have to do is to force stop whatsapp when it reaches 31% or 24%  as at (24% or 31% or 39% ) it's already finished resorting 100% of your messages
and then it will open automatically and hopefully all you messages will be there.
so when the bar reaches 31% you force it to stop. and good luck hope this work for you guys it worked for me